# How to send attribute information back to client proxy?

Tags: c#, .net, service

I need information on how to send attribute information to a client proxy. For example, I have a public class customer object which contains an ID and a Name. I add attributes to the ID and Name properties of a customer. If I add a service reference, I should get attributes attached to the ID and Name properties. I'm unable to see those attributes.

I think attributes are language features but not web features. Is there any way to accomplish this task by using a custom serializer? If so, can anyone post me a link?

I will be attaching attributes with Name and boolean values on top of the property when I add a service reference, based on the property's attribute boolean value, I am performing some task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client proxies are based on WSDL or MEX; neither includes type metadata other than that defined in WSDL / MEX - after all, what would it mean to a Java / unmanaged C++ client?

If the client is .NET, then WCF also allows assembly-sharing  - i.e. use the same DTO library at both client and server. This is best done using a shallow DTO layer that is separate to your ORM etc, and is *mainly* only used on internal applications (where you own both ends of the pipe), but attributes will be preserved (as a consequence of it being *the same dll*).

For *class*-level attributes, another option is to use a `partial class` to add the missing attributes; however, this doesn't work for members such as `ID` / `Name` (you cannot use a `partial class` to add attributes to existing members).